# No mediatype formatter found

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to call this method

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Trinity/GetDirectoryAndTask/{modelTemplateId}/{taskName}")]
    public KeyValuePair<string, string> GetDirectoryAndTask(int modelTemplateId, string taskName)
```

with the url http://localhost:46789/api/Trinity/GetDirectoryAndTask/9/AG33%2f34 but am getting a "MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'KeyValuePair`2' from content with media type 'text/html'" exception.

Comment: Sounds like you are having the same problem as this guy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512483/no-mediatypeformatter-is-available-to-read-an-object-of-type-string-from-conte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of using `/` or `%2f` in route values, I suspect that the main problem **at server side** should be:

**HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found**
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

And to solve it you can change routing to this:

```
api/Trinity/GetDirectoryAndTask/{modelTemplateId}/{*taskName}
```

To test if the server side is OK, paste the url in browser and get the result.

---

But for your **client** the error is related to the way you read data from that api. I use this code and it reads data after I changed the route:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(" http://localhost:46789/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Trinity/GetDirectoryAndTask/9/AG33%2f34");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        //The result is a valid key/value pair
    }
}
```